# Dynamic Update MySQL/PHP for fieldname / column_name

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

Can some one point me in the right direction/website here

Is there a way in PHP how you can update a particular table dynamically by comparing the field name from the FORM and the column_name from the database.

e.g

INPUT name=**"email_address"**

and

Database Column name is **email_address**

I found something but is not so flexible in my opinion...

Comment: it seems unsecure. what is the reason to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have something similar in place and it's really stable.

All you have to do is to get the
   coloumns from your table, and
   generate your input fields
   dynamically
Then, when it's posted back, implode everything, into a string. Check if the coloumn names received matches the ones in your table and implode also the values. Add_slashes and escape any quotes or other possible sql injection characters.

The following code is the one I use for a MASSIVE project/s.

```
$postvars = $_POST;
 $q = "replace into `".$opertable."`
    (
    `".(implode('`,`',(remove__v(array_keys($postvars)))))."`)
        values
    (
    '".(implode('\',\'',$postvars))."')";
```

remove__v removes some validation techniques and submit buttons etc with the function below

```
function removeObj($array) {
  foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if (substr_count($key,'obj__')) unset($array[$key]);
  }
  return $array;
}
```

all my input buttons are named as obj__*

Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to just get they key from the POST super-global, but consider the security risks involved. Remember that the form is being submitted by your user, he could easily create a fake input field called `rights`, and give himself administrator rights!

If you still want to go with it, the solution is simple. Loop over post, getting the key and value and appending it to the SQL query; as such:

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET ";
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    $sql .= $key . " = " . $value . ',';

$sql = substr($sql,0,-1);       //Remove the last comma
```

Comment: this function is only intended for the backend part of the website in which admins have access to login...

Comment: Then go ahead with it, thats a perfect example of taking shortcuts to save precious time!
Just make sure you know the risks.

Comment: Yes yes that was taken into consideration.
I will also include the table name as a input type hidden to be included into this function.. so its even more flexible and dynamic

Thanks for the time :D

Comment: Its not intended to be copy pasted, you'd have to use your head to use it in a real world scenario.

Comment: Oliver is right the submit and hidden buttons will also be submitted.. so I would go for his opinion.. But Thanks anyways it was a kickstart anyway. Thanks guys

Comment: Hearts, but yours is indeed better!